# Implementing a complex detail view using a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm working with Xcode 6.

Let's say I have a **Recipe object** which (has title, description, preparationTime, and categoryName properties) and an **array of Ingredients objects** (which is of course variable for each Recipe).
I would like to represent my detail view of a Recipe exactly like this :

[image]

So I was thinking using a single UITableViewController with dynamic prototypes (using no storyboards nor xib file for the table view) containing 3 sections and 3 arrays.

- First array : name, description, preparationTime
- Second array : categoryName
- Third array : recipe.ingredients

For the first cell, I will use a custom cell (with the help of a XIB file).
And for each section, the cell identifier will be different.

Is this a correct way to implement this Recipe detail View ?

Comment: sounds fine, but this is a question that is really just up for debate, with no definite answer so not really a question for stackoverflow

Comment: Rather than 3 array, use a single array with dictionary objects for each recipe. Also you can't implement this design with single table view, as you can't have two styles for different sections. Create a `UIView` for top-most portion and `UITableView` for next two sections.